# java.net.http HttpClient goes into loop wrapBuffer returned Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP

Tags: java, https, java-11, java-http-client

I cannot post this into JDK bug report, because I cannot reproduce it beyond my corporate infrastructure setup, but maybe somebody has encountered something similar.

**Java version:** 11.0.6

The code to build HttpClient:

```
return HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress(host, port)))
        .build();
```

My request looks like this:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(URL))
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .GET()
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("x-auth-identifier", "<credential_username>")
        .header("x-auth-key", "<credentials_password>")
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .build();
```

Using: `-Djdk.internal.httpclient.debug=true`

The interesting part is that it is successful to fetch data for the first time and then goes into loop and just spins forever (?). The second half of the log is where everything takes place.

Has anybody encountered this? I know its **Java's HttpClient** at fault, because when I swap implementations to something like RestTemplate (which internally uses Apache HttpClient), it works fine.

```
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) Unwrapped: consumed: 848
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) sending 826
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) Adding 826 to outputQ queue
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) pushScheduler is alive
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) DownstreamPusher: queue not empty, downstreamSubscription: SubscriptionBase: window = 1 cancelled = false
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) DownstreamPusher: Pushing 826 bytes downstream
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] Http1AsyncReceiver(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) Putting 826 bytes into the queue
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] Http1AsyncReceiver(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) Got 826 bytes for delegate jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$BodyReader@558115d0/parser=jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseContent$ChunkedBodyParser@57db3286
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] Http1AsyncReceiver(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) downstream subscription demand is 9223372036854775806
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] Http1AsyncReceiver(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) Forwarding 826 bytes to delegate jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$BodyReader@558115d0/parser=jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseContent$ChunkedBodyParser@57db3286
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] Http1Response(id=1, AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))) Sending 826/1376 bytes to body parser
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser Reading chunk: available 826, needed 819
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser Returning chunk bytes: 819
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser No more bytes to read - 0 yet to consume.
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser Ready to read next chunk
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser Sending chunk to consumer (819)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser Trying to read chunk len (remaining in buffer:5)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser Got chunk len 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser Trying to consume bytes: 2 (remaining in buffer: 2)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser No more chunks: 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser Chunks sent
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser done!
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] Http1AsyncReceiver(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) cleared
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 223ms] Http1Response(id=1, AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))) SSLTube(SocketTube(1)): return to HTTP/1.1 pool
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 225ms] ConnectionPool(1) registering CleanupTrigger(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 225ms] SSLTube(SocketTube(1)) connecting flows
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 225ms] SSLTube(SocketTube(1)) SSLSubscriberWrapper (reader) got delegate: CleanupTrigger(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 225ms] Http1Publisher(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) subscription cancelled
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 225ms] SSLTube(SocketTube(1)) setSubscription: demand=1, cancelled:false
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 297ms] HttpClientImpl(1) ClientImpl (async) elapsed 1005 millis for GET to <URL is Hidden> 
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 298ms] AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))/ResponseContent/ChunkedBodyParser subscriber completed
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 298ms] Http1Response(id=1, AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))) Finished reading body: READING_BODY
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 298ms] Http1Response(id=1, AsyncSSLTunnelConnection(SSLTube(SocketTube(1)))) Operation finished: decrementing ref count for jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl@41659a39(1)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 298ms] Http1AsyncReceiver(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) Delegate done: 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 298ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) upstreamWindowUpdate, downstreamQueueSize:0, upstreamWindow:1
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 298ms] Http1AsyncReceiver(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) Http1TubeSubscriber: dropSubscription
2020-05-28 09:28:03.525  WARN 1 --- [nio-4000-exec-4] l.n.proxy.handlers.ProxyRequestHandler   : RESPONSE OUT #65f3e430-525e-4546-86dc-20eb23f399f5
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 298ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) DownstreamPusher: queue empty, downstreamSubscription: SubscriptionBase: window = 1 cancelled = false
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [177s 298ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) DownstreamPusher: queue empty, downstreamSubscription: SubscriptionBase: window = 1 cancelled = false
2020-05-28 09:28:03.529  WARN 1 --- [nio-4000-exec-4] l.n.proxy.handlers.PutToCacheHandler     : Adding to cache #65f3e430-525e-4546-86dc-20eb23f399f5
2020-05-28 09:28:03.533  WARN 1 --- [nio-4000-exec-4] l.n.proxy.handlers.PutToCacheHandler     : Save conditions passed for #65f3e430-525e-4546-86dc-20eb23f399f5
2020-05-28 09:28:03.559  WARN 1 --- [nio-4000-exec-4] lt.northstar.proxy.Endpoint              : Returning GET '<URL is Hidden>' with 200 OK #65f3e430-525e-4546-86dc-20eb23f399f5

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------GOES INTO LOOP--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SelectorAttachment Registering jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent@2bf8cf41 for 0 (false)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SocketTube(1) read bytes: 24
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) onNext
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) Adding 24 bytes to read buffer
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) upstreamWindowUpdate, downstreamQueueSize:0, upstreamWindow:0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) requesting 1
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SocketTube(1) got some demand for reading
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SocketTube(1) resuming read event
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SelectorAttachment Registering jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent@2bf8cf41 for 1 (false)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 155ms] SocketTube(1) leaving request(1):  Reading: [ops=1, demand=1, stopped=false], Writing: [ops=0, demand=1]
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 156ms] SocketTube(1) resuming read event
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 156ms] SelectorAttachment Registering jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent@2bf8cf41 for 1 (false)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 156ms] SocketTube(1) leaving read() loop after onNext:  Reading: [ops=1, demand=1, stopped=false], Writing: [ops=0, demand=1]
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 156ms] SelectorAttachment Registering jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent@2bf8cf41 for 0 (false)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 156ms] SocketTube(1) got read EOF
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 156ms] SocketTube(1) pausing read event
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 159ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) processData: readBuf remaining:24, state: NOT_HANDSHAKING , engine handshake status:NOT_HANDSHAKING
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 159ms] SSL Reader(SocketTube(1)) Unwrapping: 24
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 159ms] SelectorAttachment Registering jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent@2bf8cf41 for 0 (false)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [192s 159ms] SocketTube(1) completing subscriber
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSLFlowDelegate(SocketTube(1)) doClosure(Status = CLOSED HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 24 bytesProduced = 0): NEED_WRAP [isOutboundDone: false, isInboundDone: true]
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSLFlowDelegate(SocketTube(1)) doClosure: close_notify received
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) processData, writeList remaining:0, hsTriggered:true, needWrap:true
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) wrapping 0 bytes
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) SSLResult: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) OK => produced: 0 bytes into 0, not wrapped: 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) wrapBuffer returned Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) handshaking
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) wrapping 0 bytes
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) SSLResult: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) OK => produced: 0 bytes into 0, not wrapped: 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) wrapBuffer returned Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) handshaking
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) wrapping 0 bytes
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) SSLResult: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) OK => produced: 0 bytes into 0, not wrapped: 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) wrapBuffer returned Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) handshaking
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) wrapping 0 bytes
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-1] [192s 162ms] SSL Writer(SocketTube(1)) SSLResult: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0
.........................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably JDK-8214418 which has been fixed in JDK 12. It's also been backported to Oracle JDK 11.0.4. The issue is not directly visible but you should find all the information in public review thread here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2019-January/019142.html

Comment: But I'm using 11.0.6. It should have been fixed.

Comment: I believe it will be in Open JDK 11.0.8 as well.

Comment: Alright. Will test it once that is released. Thank you

Comment: You could already test with the latest released JDK (14) - it shouldn't reproduce there either.

Comment: Can't. Corporate policy. Only JDK 11 images are allowed. And that particular case is only visible when its deployed to corporate infrastructure.